# [Competitive Programming]:How do I optimise this brute force method?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am being given the lengths of a few lines and I am required to find how many of those will form a triangle

The Input is like this

```
7 
1 4 13 2 25 6 11
```

where 7 is the no. of lines and the following lines contains length of all the lines.

This is what my code looks like at its core

```
    for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){ //n is the total no. of lines given initially
        for(int j=i+1;j<n-1;j++){
            for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++){
                if(l[i]+l[j]>l[k]){
                    noOfTriangles++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

And even though the code works as expected, right now it takes time of the order of n^3 which exceeds the time limit for some inputs . Anyway I could optimise it?

EDIT: I forgot to mention I have first sorted my array before implementing nested-for loop.

Comment: what do u want, total possible triangles combinations or the maximum number of triangles that can be made using all lines??

Comment: You may first sort your input.

Comment: Maybe a sorted array like on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) could be a good approach. I would recommend to add the tags `optimization` and `performance`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have sorted the input before using the nested loops.

Comment: @RajeevSingh Maximum number of triangles possible taking 3 lines at a time.